# How to change Google chrome version?

Tags: google-chrome, osx-snow-leopard, imac

I am using imac snow leopard 10.6.8 and for quite some time I was able to make mac believe Skype is of newer version to make it work.
I am wondering is it possible to do that with Google Chrome? 
Because it keeps crashing the moment I try to type something into www window or search engine.

Comment: What version of chrome are you running? Why do you believe artificially changing the version will help instead of reinstalling or updating it? If you are able to reach a search engine you should be able to reach a page? Does it report anything on crash? When did that start happening? Are you able to reach pages without www?

Comment: changing the version of the software being reported won't stop the software from crashing.

Comment: I was running version 49.n.nnnn something. Because it fooled Skype. And worked for quite some time. Its old chrome. I can click in it but as soon as I start writing, it crashes. It does but I have no clue what it means. Google stopped supporting older versions for old imacs. Less than a week ago. No, it crashes.

Comment: Error i receive is 66.3k characters too long for here. 
 so I uploaded it here https://textuploader.com/1ro34 and there is still 6333 characters missing.